# Nsmutable array crashing

Tags: nsmutablearray

While adding Nsdate values to NSmutablearray my app gets  crashing.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {


markarry=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

HolidayAppDelegate *delegatObj = (HolidayAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

for (int i=0;i<[delegatObj.Datearray count]; i++) {

    NSString *Str=[delegatObj.Datearray objectAtIndex:i];

    NSLog(@"dates %@",Str);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM-dd-yyyy"];

    NSDate *dateFromString;
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:Str];

    NSLog(@"date type %@",dateFromString);
    [markarry addObject:dateFromString];
    [dateFromString release];
    [Str release];

}
}
```

If I don't release dateFromString and Str,it also gets crashing.
Help me here.

This is the error Iam getting on console.

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
   reason:    -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object
   at 12' Call stack at first throw:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reason:    -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object
```

dateFromString will return nil if the string isnt a valid date. So my guess is its returning nil, and then that causes the exception.

Edit: is MMMM really what you want? See: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Edit: Yes, MMMM is what you wanted. Hmmm.

Comment: Hi jamie,I have  string like this @"February-24-2012".I need to convert it into 2012-02-24 00:00:00 +0000.But with above code Iam geeting this 2012-02-23 18:30:00 +0000.And also the last value as null.

Comment: Ok, a) you've got time zone issues, but b) what is the last date string that gives you the last null?

Comment: October-26-2012 2012-10-25 18:30:00 +0000,
Novermber-28-2012 (null). These are the last 2 string values Iam getting.

Comment: jamie Iam not getting nil now,but Nsdateformatter never returning exact date as my date.

Comment: The +0000 is telling you that the string you are seeing is UTC time zone. The date formatter will be in your time zone (I believe), but when you NSLog it, it will display in UTC. Does that make sense? Are you 5:30 hours ahead of UTC?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the exception you're getting **clearly** states, you're attempting to insert a `nil` object to the `NSMutableArray`.

So I suppose `[dateFormatter dateFromString:Str]` returns `nil`, and you shouldn't insert it to the array.